# Can't write to file in Flask on win 8

Tags: python, flask

I am getting an IO permission denied error when writing to a file in Flask. It's a test app running locally on a win 8 machine. Any ideas on what I might be missing?
Thanks Brian

```
   from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
         with open("test.txt", "a") as fo:
            fo.write("This is Test Data")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Some additional context?

Answer (score 0):

"IO permission denied error when writing to a file in Flask"

That line gives you hint that flask has no permission to write that path.
Be sure that Flask has permission to write files that file location.

Comment: Thanks for your help folks - the primary issue was that I wasn't running Pycharm as administrator, and the built in IDE server didn't like it. But now I'm getting some more odd behaviour in that the file creation code is no longer throwing an exception but is just quietly failing to write to either my root or any child directories. Any clue as to what might be happening?

Comment: So share your log with us. Before that enable debug=True at app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user who the web server is running under has permissions to write to the folder where you expect `test.txt` to be created. If you are running it as yourself then make sure you are launching it from a directory where you have write access.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - but how do I set the permissions? I personally have full admin access. I am using Pycharm 5 and its built-in Flask project template. I have no issues writing to my PyCharmProjects directories when using a standalone Python app.